# Map alignment is off

Tags: qgis

[image]

I imported the shapefiles from a government source but it looks like the land masses arent't aligned properly even though the crs on all layers are the same.

Comment: The declared CRS is wrong. The coordinate looks like being in lat-long, with values in degrees suitable for UTM 19 (CRS 26919)

Comment: I have all of the layers set to crs 26919, i'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: right click on the layer, `CRS`, `set layer CRS`

Comment: Yes they're all set to 26919 and it still looks like that

Comment: Can you share the source of the data?

Comment: https://ftp.maps.canada.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/index/html/geospatial_product_index_en.html#link

I used 24m, 24n, 25c, and 25d

Comment: This dataset is not in UTM but rather is unprojected, using Nad83 datum. Try setting the CRS to 4617. You can get this value from the [metadata](https://open.canada.ca/data/api/action/package_show?id=97126362-5a85-4fe0-9dc2-915464cfdbb7) (near the bottom) or the xml metadata coming with the shapefile (look for `<gmd:referenceSystemInfo>`) or to a lesser extent from the cryptic `prj` file (though the epsg code is not stated there)

Comment: I tried it and got the same results unfortunately

Comment: 1) What exactly is looking wrong? Have you tried styling the classes properly to select what you want to see on the map?
2) What made you override the layers' CRS? That should not be necessary. I am asking because it might have been misguidance of QGIS itself.

Answer (score 2):

The layer I downloaded had an EPSG of 4326, which is a geographic CRS. Right clicking and setting a different CRS is not enough - this way you are just confusing QGIS, telling it that 1 degree is 1 m.

You should reproject your layers first.

- Import your layer anew, making sure that QGIS knows that they have an a geographic CRS (usually it will automatically recognize the EPSG of a shapefile).
- Right click on the layer --> Export --> Save Features as.. and save the layer, giving it a new CRS (in your case 26919):

[image: reprojecting to EPSG:26191]

QGIS is going to ask you for the transformation algorithm you want to use; in any case, it will be accurate down to 1-4 m.

Now that you have a new layer that has been reprojected, you can do your analysis and mapping. Don't forget to choose the right CRS for your overall project from the bottom right button.

Comment: See here for background and explanation of "changing" CRS vs. reprojecting: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814