# Scale bar wrong on QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping, scale-bar

[image]

The scale bar is very off, I believe the length of the scale bar shown should cover 20-40 km in this area easily. I have everything on the project and layers set to epsg: 26919. As you can see the ratio is 1:9 because I am using imported shapefiles only for this area.

Comment: what is the projection of your project? I'd guess it's in degrees

Comment: how do i figure out if it's in degrees or not?

Comment: it is the same issue as in your previous [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371892/map-alignment-is-off?noredirect=1#comment607384_371892): your data is not in UTM but is rather unprojected (CRS 4617). You first need to set the proper CRS on the layers. As it is, you have a layer in degrees and have instructed QGIS that it is in meters instead.... so 1 degree becomes 1 meter, which is obviously wrong

Comment: Usually the clue it is in degrees is things like the scale bar is off.

Comment: i'll add another photo but all of my layers are set to UTM 19/ EPSG: 26919, i've edited all of them individually

Comment: Somewhere in your process the wrong projection was assigned to the layer (maybe a misuse between `set crs`, which just change the projection code and `project`, which actually transform the coordinates). You need to go back and fix this mistake first (i.e. `set` the CRS to 4617), then you can `project` the data to 26919.

Comment: I have tried to export the shapefiles with the crs set tp 26919 and added them back to my project but perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Which QGIS version? Did you check this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34926

Comment: I actually am using 3.10.2 maybe that's the problem? I'll try to do what the user did to the prj file